# Operation not permitted - unlink on local machine

Tags: php

Im trying to unlink a folder on the local version of my site.

I get the error:

```
operation not permitted
```

Any ideas how I can get unlink to work on my local machine? Im using MAMP.

Comment: What do you mean by "local machine"? The *client* or the *server*?

Comment: Have you checked directory permission for that target folder?

Comment: As in, im testing the website on my local machine before uploading to the server.

Comment: Please copy the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: Also, **show the code** that is causing the error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/unlink):

> unlink — Deletes a **file**

and

> See Also: [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir)() - Removes directory

You have a directory. You need to use `rmdir`, not `unlink`.

Comment: rmdir: failed to remove 'directory_name': Directory not empty

Answer (score 2):

It means the script is not allowed to delete the folder. This can have various reasons - the most likely one is that you are trying to [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) a folder instead of using [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/rmdir) to delete it.

Here are the possible reasons for "operation not permitted" (EPERM) from the `unlink(2)` man page:

> **EPERM**  The system does not allow unlinking of directories, or unlinking of directories requires privileges that the calling process
>   doesn't have.  (This is the POSIX prescribed error return<strike>; as noted
>   above, Linux returns EISDIR for this case.</strike>)
>
> <strike>**EPERM (Linux only)**
>       The file system does not allow unlinking of files.</strike>
>
> **EPERM or EACCES**
>       The directory containing pathname has the sticky bit (S_ISVTX) set and the process's effective UID is neither the UID of
>   the file to be deleted nor that  of  the  directory  containing  it, 
>   and  the process is not privileged <strike>(Linux: does not have the CAP_FOWNER capability)</strike>.

Answer (score -1):

This is a permissions problem.

Try giving the file you want unlink permissions like CHMOD 666.

You probably created the file yourself and want PHP (another user then yourself, probably Apache or www-data depending on how MAMP is installed) to delete the file for you - without the right permissions, this cannot be done.

Comment: Why would you want the *executable* bit to delete a file? I know it's incredibly common in the PHP world to simply CHMOD 777 everything that should be writable by PHP scripts which often run as the apache user, but write permissions are enough for this. Actually, you only need write permissions on the parent folder - the file itself can be owned by anyone and have any permissions as long as you can write to the folder and it's doesn't have the sticky bit.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's just a bad habit... I usually use CHMOD 666 myself, but I see your point. Updated my answer.